# SQLiteOpenHelper.setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled causes an error log line

Tags: android, android-sqlite

When I call

```
setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled(true);
```

in the constructor of my SQLiteOpenHelper subclass, the first time the database is used, after it is created, I can see the following error log item:

```
02-07 18:16:05.131  10426-10426/com.test E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such table: test
```

When the application is killed and started subsequent times, I get:

```
E/SQLiteLog﹕ (283) recovered 10 frames from WAL file /data/data/com.test/databases/test-wal
```

However, the application works fine and no exception is actually thrown.

When I don't enable WAL, the log item is not there.

Is the log error something to worry about?

**Edit**: the code of my `DbHelper`:

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, Db.NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

    // setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onConfigure(db);

    db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
    db.enableWriteAheadLogging();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(Db.TestGroup._CREATE_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(Db.Test._CREATE_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(Db.Task._CREATE_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(Db.TaskFullTextSearch._CREATE_TABLE);

    db.execSQL(Db.TaskFullTextSearch.Triggers.AFTER_INSERT);
    db.execSQL(Db.TaskFullTextSearch.Triggers.BEFORE_UPDATE);
    db.execSQL(Db.TaskFullTextSearch.Triggers.AFTER_UPDATE);
    db.execSQL(Db.TaskFullTextSearch.Triggers.BEFORE_DELETE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // nothing
}

public int getTestCount() {
    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(SELECT_TEST_COUNT, null);
    cursor.moveToNext();
    int count = cursor.getInt(0);
    cursor.close();

    return count;
}
}
```

The DB class is a 'contract' class and defines the table classes and columns and a bunch of SQL statements.

The database helper is a singleton created in a custom Application subclass:

```
public class TestApplication extends Application {

private static DbHelper DB_HELPER;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    DB_HELPER = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext());
}

public static DbHelper getDbHelper() {
    return DB_HELPER;
}
}
```

**Edit 2**: I've just checked what happens when there really is no `test` table - the application crashes with:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.test, PID: 30663
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: test (code 1): , while compiling: select count(*) from test
```

Comment: Changing the write-ahead logging configuration should be done in the `onConfigure()` callback method of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` along with all other configuration changes. The `SQLiteDatebase` isn't even initialized in the constructor, so doing it there would have no effect. I don't see why it should output that log though. Are you sure it's logged at _that_ point? Do you have a table named "test"?

Comment: The method I talk about is a SQLiteOpenHelper method has a bunch of checks, and if there is already a database open, it applies a new setting to it. At the end, it sets its internal field: mEnableWriteAheadLogging = enabled; which is used the next time the database is opened. I think you mixed it up with the other method: SQLiteDatabase.enable/disableWriteAheadLogging, which needs a database instance to be called upon. Nowhere does the documentation say when the method is to be called, and it actually does work when called in the constructor (barring the log error).

Comment: The error is not logged at the point when WAL is enabled, it is done when the first statement is executed, which in my case is 'select count(*) from test'. And yes, I do have a 'test' table. The strange thing is that although the error is logged (only this single line, no stack trace no nothing), the whole application works fine.

Comment: When I use SQLiteDatabase.enableWriteAheadLogging() in onConfigure, the result is the same - the error line in the log and an otherwise perfectly working application. Not enabling WAL produces no error log line.

Comment: Where are you performing the query from? Please post the relevant code and details.

Comment: Posted the code. The query is performed from a normal method which is invoked after the db has been created etc. Please note that, as mentioned, the problem / log error entry is shown only when the database is first created; subsequent application starts don't show this.

Comment: I just noticed that subsequent application starts show a different log entry, about recovering WAL frames - updated the original question.

Comment: I have added an answer. You were right about the `setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled()` method behavior in `SQLiteOpenHelper` though. It is implemented so that it can be called at any point with correct results.

Comment: What does "setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled" actually do exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some experimentation, it appears that for some reason SQLite keeps a cached list of tables as part of the metadata associated with opened connections. Creating a new table only updates the cache on the connection that was used to do it. If a connection is used to perform some operation on a table that is not included in it's cached metadata, then it complains about the table not existing, even though the operation itself is performed successfully (and the cache subsequently updated).

The connection pool used by `SQLiteDatabase` currently allows only one connection for both read and write operations if write-ahead logging is not enabled, presumably in order to avoid errors caused by a read operation performed while a writer has an exclusive lock on the database. If write-ahead logging is enabled, then it allows at least one separate read connection in addition to the primary write connection (the exact limit on read connections is defined by a system property).

`SQLiteOpenHelper` opens a read connection for getting the version information *before* opening the write connection that is used for database initialization and upgrades/downgrades. If write-ahead logging is not enabled, then they are both the same connection. However, if write-ahead logging is enabled *before* initialization, the read connection's cache does not reflect any structural changes performed during initialization (and SQLite complains about that in the log when the first query is performed). This can be fixed by enabling write-ahead logging from the `onOpen()` method, which is called after the initialization is completed.

As for the log about frame recovery, that's caused by the fact that SQLite checkpoints and deletes the WAL files when all the connections are closed. If the process holding the connections is terminated without explicitly closing them, then this cleanup is performed when a new connection is subsequently opened, and SQLite complains about it. If you close the `SQLiteDatabase` whenever your application is moved to the background, then this issue should be resolved. On the other hand, if you are interacting with the database throughout your app, then that might be problematic and difficult to implement, and I wouldn't recommend doing it.

Comment: Thanks. So I will just consider the first error message (about the missing table) to be a spurious one, a nuisance but otherwise harmless.

Comment: It won't be easy for me to close the connections. As you mentioned yourself in one of mine other topics, the open helper is supposed to be used as a singleton for the app. Where I can start it in Application.onCreate(), there is no way to stop it, I guess. I could close and open the singleton connection in activities onPause/onResume, but I find it very inconvenient to say the least. I might try to do it, though.

Comment: @wujek: Yes, I agree that closing the `SQLiteDatabase` would be quite complex to implement correctly, and in fact probably not worth doing if you don't want to requery all your cursors when your app is brought back to the foreground. If you want to do it though, you can ask a new question on how to properly implement it, and I will provide some tips. There is no real issue with not explicitly closing the database (except for SQLite complaining about it), so you should probably not bother with it unless there is some logical point for doing so.